WS02 APIM 4.1.0: High CPU Utilization over 100% and HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher threads consuming %CPU

WSO2 APIM Server : 4.1.0
OpenJDK : 64-Bit Server VM (11.0.17+8-LTS mixed mode, sharing)
Linux : RHEL 8.x
CPU/Processor : 4
Memory : 8GB

WSO2 APIM 4.1.0 running on OpenJDK 11 continues to shows 100% more CPU utilization when being used in an environment with average throughput. CPU usage will remain in more than 100% figures and the issue will be resolved after restarting the server. After running for couple of days, the problem is re occurring and only a restart is the work around now.
Thread Usage shows HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher threads consuming more CPU and and all other threads are showing normal figures.
%CPU  CPU  NI S     TIME     PID     TID

65.3   -   0 R 98-06:31:07 1786915 1787000  (Decimal ->  **1b4478**)

78.9   -   0 R 118-14:04:13 1786915 1787001 (Decimal -> **1b4479**)

 1.0   -   0 R 1-13:32:03 1786915 1787002   (Decimal -> 1b447a)

 3.9   -   0 R 5-21:18:34 1786915 1787003   (Decimal -> 1b447b)

 1.7   -   0 S 2-15:00:19 1786915 1787200   (Decimal -> 1b4540)

> 1.5   -   0 S 2-09:38:23 1786915 1786922   (Decimal -> 1b442a)

Thread dump for the HTTP sender threads is given below,
HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1" #68 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=**8490642866.44ms** elapsed=12983070.78s tid=0x00007f325801c800 nid=0x**1b4478** runnable  [0x00007f3241dc7000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:280)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)

"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2" #69 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=**10245828487.59ms** elapsed=12983070.78s tid=0x00007f325835c000 nid=0x**1b4479** runnable  [0x00007f3241cc7000]
       java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
        at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:787)
        - **locked** <0x00000000f28b12b8> (a org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException)
        at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:270)
        at java.lang.Exception.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Exception.java:66)
        at java.io.IOException.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/IOException.java:58)
        at org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException.<init>(MalformedChunkCodingException.java:54)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.readChunkHead(ChunkDecoder.java:112)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.read(ChunkDecoder.java:205)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.produce(Pipe.java:250)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetResponse.read(TargetResponse.java:164)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler.inputReady(TargetHandler.java:606)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpClientConnection.java:115)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:83)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:41)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)
"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-3" #70 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=**135099517.41ms** elapsed=12983070.78s tid=0x00007f3258230000 nid=0x1b447a runnable  [0x00007f3241bc6000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.read(ChunkDecoder.java:205)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.produce(Pipe.java:250)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetResponse.read(TargetResponse.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler.inputReady(TargetHandler.java:606)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpClientConnection.java:115)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:41)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)

"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-4" #71 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=**508690354.93ms** elapsed=12983070.78s tid=0x00007f3258231000 nid=0x1b447b runnable  [0x00007f3241ac5000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:787)
    - **locked** <0x00000000f244f4b0> (a org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:270)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Exception.java:66)
    at java.io.IOException.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/IOException.java:58)
    at org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException.<init>(MalformedChunkCodingException.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.readChunkHead(ChunkDecoder.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.read(ChunkDecoder.java:205)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.produce(Pipe.java:250)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetResponse.read(TargetResponse.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler.inputReady(TargetHandler.java:606)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpClientConnection.java:115)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:41)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)

Looking into any other metrics or logs can help to root cause the problem. Please assist.
We have not applied any much performance tuning in the system, there are only 10 API definitions and only two applications subscribing to the same. There is a load balancer placed in-front (Apache Web Server) and the load is distributed between two WSO2 APIM servers. All the API definitions uses the OKTA key Manager with introspect enabled for JWT validation. The connections to the OKTA servers (public internet traffic) are directed through an internal proxy server (running on HTTP). Connections to the back end services are plain HTTP. There are multiple instances of back end services which are configured using Fail Over configuration in the APIM Publisher portal for every API's.
Edit:July 08
We took the head dump as suggested and found the below details in HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-3 under the IOSessionImpl object -> bufferStatus -> buffer ->

hb byte [8192] @0xc68ae770 //response from back end api here [only a
chunk of around 1024 bytes]// with shallow and retained heap as 8208.

Similar bufferStatus found for HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-4 thread. Please note, both of them are executed for the same API request and dealing with the API response in chunks. Couple of threads were executing org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder and couple of them are in waiting state. But none of the HTTP sender dispatcher threads were in MalformedChunkCodingException class.
We have collected one more thread dump and found the same IO dispatcher threads occupying more CPU. This time 3 out of 4 HTTP Sender IO threads are occupying the CPU. When we took the thread dump again (after taking heap dump) we found one of the thread executing MalformedChunkCodingException.
%CPU CPU  NI S     TIME     PID     TID
27.9   -   0 R 8-10:56:54 1675674 1675759
62.0   -   0 R 18-18:07:14 1675674 1675760
49.0   -   0 R 14-19:47:42 1675674 1675761

Here are the new thread dump for those.
"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-1" #68 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=165568.85ms elapsed=2611174.27s tid=0x00007fa8b8001800 nid=0x1991ee runnable  [0x00007fa8923fc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.17/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.17/SelectorImpl.java:124)
    - locked <0x00000000c92ef8b0> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000c92ef858> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.17/SelectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)

"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-2" #69 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=730598183.23ms elapsed=2611174.26s tid=0x00007fa8b801f800 nid=0x1991ef runnable  [0x00007fa8922fb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    at java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:787)
    - locked <0x00000000ea570ba0> (a org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Throwable.java:270)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/Exception.java:66)
    at java.io.IOException.<init>(java.base@11.0.17/IOException.java:58)
    at org.apache.http.MalformedChunkCodingException.<init>(MalformedChunkCodingException.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.readChunkHead(ChunkDecoder.java:112)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.read(ChunkDecoder.java:205)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.produce(Pipe.java:250)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetResponse.read(TargetResponse.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler.inputReady(TargetHandler.java:606)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpClientConnection.java:115)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:41)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)

"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-3" #70 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1620418247.95ms elapsed=2611174.26s tid=0x00007fa8b8021000 nid=0x1991f0 runnable  [0x00007fa8921fa000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.EPoll.wait(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(java.base@11.0.17/EPollSelectorImpl.java:120)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(java.base@11.0.17/SelectorImpl.java:124)
    - locked <0x00000000c92f0ae8> (a sun.nio.ch.Util$2)
    - locked <0x00000000c92f0988> (a sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl)
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(java.base@11.0.17/SelectorImpl.java:136)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:255)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)

"HTTP-Sender I/O dispatcher-4" #71 prio=5 os_prio=0 cpu=1280846024.20ms elapsed=2611174.26s tid=0x00007fa8b8023000 nid=0x1991f1 runnable  [0x00007fa8920f9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(java.base@11.0.17/Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(java.base@11.0.17/SocketDispatcher.java:39)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(java.base@11.0.17/IOUtil.java:276)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(java.base@11.0.17/IOUtil.java:245)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(java.base@11.0.17/IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(java.base@11.0.17/SocketChannelImpl.java:356)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SessionInputBufferImpl.fill(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:231)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.AbstractContentDecoder.fillBufferFromChannel(AbstractContentDecoder.java:129)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.codecs.ChunkDecoder.read(ChunkDecoder.java:195)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.Pipe.produce(Pipe.java:250)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetResponse.read(TargetResponse.java:164)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.TargetHandler.inputReady(TargetHandler.java:606)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.DefaultNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(DefaultNHttpClientConnection.java:265)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.http.conn.LoggingNHttpClientConnection.consumeInput(LoggingNHttpClientConnection.java:115)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:83)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientIODispatch.onInputReady(ClientIODispatch.java:41)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:114)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@11.0.17/Thread.java:829)


It seems one of your http backend end sends invalid chunk messages which fail while reading it from ChunkDecoder. First, we need to identify the invalid response. Could you please refer to the blog post in[1] and try to identify the invalid response?
As explained in the blog, let's find the org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.IOSessionImpl object related to high CPU consuming thread. Then let's expand the object and you will be able to find a appbufferstatus object. There you need to check inbuf to get the payload. Let's use mat memory analyzer to check the heap dump.
[1] https://medium.com/@prabhashdilhanakmeemana/how-to-tackle-java-high-cpu-issues-in-a-production-environment-and-identify-the-root-cause-54007737123c

Thanks for the suggestions Dil. We took the heap dump as you advised and did an analysis. The details are added to the question. However this time we don't find any HTTP send thread executing Malformed Exception from Chunk Decoder. But when we took a next thread dump immediately it is executing Malformed Exception.

We looked into the source code of Chunk Decoder readHead line no 112 and found below.... if (this.buffer.length() > 2 || this.endOfStream) {
throw new MalformedChunkCodingException("CRLF expected at end of chunk");
}.... Is this related the size of JSON response back end service respond? We will try to take one more dump and see if we can capture the dump while it is executing the above exception
